# System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name is Works

Tags: asp.net-membership

I am using `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` (with windows authentication in my web.config) to get the client username.

My question is whether this code works when I put the page onto the intranet, because I need to store the username within the session for later use.

Will I be able to get the username the user used to log into my page using this code?

```
void Authenticate()
{
    string strLogin = null;

    try
    {
        strLogin = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
        Session.Add("Login", strLogin);
        //Label1.Text = strLogin;
        //Label2.Text = System.Environment.UserName;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(strLogin);
        Response.Write("<br/>handled:" + ex.Message.ToString());
        Response.End();
    }
    finally
    {
        GC.Collect();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You will need to configure the application to impersonate the Windows user who is accessing it by adding the following element after the authentication element in the Web.Config:

```
<identity impersonate="true"/>
```

If you do not set impersonate to true then the worker process runs as the Network Service or ASPNET account, depending on your version of IIS.

Comment: thanks for the replies.How could i test this windows authentication in local machine as i dont have intranet,and systems under domain.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. and it also works in Page.User.Identity.Name

Answer (score 0):

If your users logon on your website, the you can get the name of the current user with Page.User.Identity.Name.